# MySql SELECT items of a list and their name item stored in another table?

Tags: mysql

I have  to manage lists of items , so i built a table for the lists `list_tb`,one `item_tb` for the items (same item can be in more lists) and one table `item_to_list_tb` for the relation between item and lists

`item_tb` and `item_to_list_tb` they have in common `item_id`

`list_id` and `item_to_list_tb` they have in common `list_id`

each row of item_tb contains the name of the product so here i'm trying to get all the items that belong to a list $ID, and their name...i tried this but doesn't work well...

```
SELECT  item_to_list_tb.*, item_tb.*
FROM item_to_list_tb
LEFT JOIN item_tb ON item_tb.item_id = item_tb.item_id
WHERE   item_to_list_tb.list_id= $ID
GROUP BY item_tb.item_id 
ORDER BY item_to_list_tb.item_ord
```

bottom line i need to retrieve a bunch of items aong with their name, stored in a different table...

whats the best practice? thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by "it doesn't work well"?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
SELECT item_tb.* FROM item_tb LEFT JOIN item_to_list_tb USING (item_id) WHERE item_to_list_db.list_id=$i
```